# Trying to solve $x^2=\frac 1{\ln x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone help me solve $x^2=\dfrac 1{\ln x}$ ? I don't have any idea.

Is there any way to solve it with exponentials?

I already proved the existence of the solution by IVT. Indeed the function $f(x)=1/x\ln x$ is strictly decreasing in $]1;+\infty[$ with $\lim_{x\to 1^+} f(x)= +\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)= 0$, so it has to cross the $y=x$ line once.

Comment: $x=\sqrt{\frac{2}{W(2)}}$

Comment: No - there are no elementary-function solutions.

Comment: Thanks for answering ! what is W(2) ?

Comment: Firsly you should show that a solution exists.

Comment: The Lambert omega function.

Comment: Could you please add some details, how have you proved the existence of a solution? If you add that I'll add some more detail to the answer. Thanks

Comment: @gimusi $1/\log x$ is decreasing from $\infty$ to $0$ and $x^2$ is increasing from $0$ to $\infty$. They cross once.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Yes you are right that's seems simpler!

Answer (score 2):

As already said, solve it numerically for 
$$x\simeq 1.531584$$
The analytical solution cannot be expressed with a finite number of elementary functions. It requires a special function, the Lambert W function.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html

$$x^2=\frac{1}{\ln(x)}=\frac{2}{\ln(x^2)}$$
$$\ln(x^2)=\frac{2}{x^2}$$
$$x^2=e^{2/x^2}$$
$$\frac{2}{x^2}e^{2/x^2}=2$$
Let $X=\frac{2}{x^2}$
$$Xe^X=2$$
From the definition of the Lambert W function :
$$X=W(2)$$
Thus $\frac{2}{x^2}=W(2)$

$$x=\sqrt{\frac{2}{W(2)}}$$
$W(2)\simeq 0.8526055$

Comment: Brilliant ! thank you very much ! :)))

Answer (score 1):

The first thing, as you have made, is to show/check that there is exactly a solution for $x>1$ by [IVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).

To determine that value by [*numerical methods*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) (Newton's, bisection, etc.) we can use bisection method by a calculator starting for example from

- $x_a=1 \implies f(1)<0$
- $x_b=2 \implies f(2)>0$

and then we can iteretively get closer and closer to the solution by

- $x_i=\frac{x_a+x_b}2$
- if $f(x_i)<0 \implies x_a=f(x_i)$
- if $f(x_i)>0 \implies x_b=f(x_i)$

Here is the numerical solution by [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=roots%20x%5E2(ln%20x)-1) that is $x \approx 1.5316$.

Comment: Thanks ! I already proved that it existed by IVT, by i'm stuck with the numerical methods...

Comment: @Jean That's fine, you need to add all those informations directly in your question in order to clarify what are you asking exactly.

Comment: Alright, done ! Can you tell me what you mean by numerical methods ? @gimusi

Comment: @Jean You need first to improve your answer adding more detail and context about your work on that. Thanks

Comment: So it is like dichotomy program ?

Comment: Anyway, thank you so much !

Comment: @Jean Yes that's the simplest method! You can also use excel for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use Lambert function, consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=\log(x)-\frac 1{x^2}$$ for which
$$f'(x)=\frac{2}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x}> 0 \,\,\,\, \forall x\qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x)=-\frac{6}{x^4}-\frac{1}{x^2} < 0 \,\,\,\, \forall x$$
The first derivative does not show real roots. By inspection $f(1)=-1$ and $f(2)=\log (2)-\frac{1}{4}$
Build a Taylor series at $x=1$ to get
$$f(x)=-1+3 (x-1)+O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$ giving the approximate solution  $\frac 4 3$. 
Using instead the simplest Padé approximant, you would have
$$f(x)\sim \frac{17-11 x}{1-7 x}$$ giving the approximate solution  $\frac {17}{11}\approx 1.54545 $ which is not too bad compared to the exact value.

**Edit**

You could have better approximations if you notice that $f\left(\sqrt{e}\right)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{e}$. So, using Taylor again
$$f(x)=\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{e}\right)+\frac{(2+e)
   \left(x-\sqrt{e}\right)}{e^{3/2}}+O\left(\left(x-\sqrt{e}\right)^2\right)$$ which gives as an estimate
$$x=\frac{\sqrt{e} (6+e)}{2 (2+e)}\approx 1.52323$$

Doing the same with the simplest Padé approximant, we should get
$$f(x)\sim\frac{(4+5 e (4+e)) x-\sqrt{e} (6+e) (2+3 e)}{2 e (6+e) x+2 (e-2) e^{3/2}}$$ giving as an estimate
$$x=\frac{\sqrt{e} (6+e) (2+3 e)}{4+5 e (4+e)}\approx 1.53147$$

Comment: I think that on this you can teach us a lot!

Comment: Really I think that, also for this, your contribution here is so important and special for that! There is not price to see how you work on that. Thanks